# Input Email and Checkbox validation to Enable Submit button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ninja-forms

I have the following javascript code for a form in which I validate email with certain patterns and a checkbox with I agree with T&C label. If any of them failed then I disable the submit button. It is all working but I am using too many functions which are causing some conflicts in which if one condition gets true then submit button is available to click.

I am not able to verify both conditions at the same time because both are of different types. There are some answers on Stack overflow but they are of the same type of fields like 2 inputs, 3 checkboxes but not different fields.

Here's the code:

```
    window.onload = function ninjaInit() {
  validatEmail();
    validatCheckbox();
  jQuery('#nf-field-20').keyup(validatEmail);
    jQuery('#nf-field-13').change(validatCheckbox);
  }

function validatEmail() {
  var email = document.getElementById('nf-field-20');
    //console.log(email.value);
  if (
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!yahoo.co.in)(?!aol.com)(?!live.com)(?!outlook.com)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{2,61}$/.test(email.value)) {
    itWorksem();
  } else {
    notWorkingem();
  }
}
function validatCheckbox() {
    if(!jQuery('#nf-field-13').hasClass("nf-checked")){
             console.log('checkbox not checked');
        checkBoGood();
             }else{
             console.log('checkbox checked');
              checkBoBad();
             }
}
    
function itWorksem() {
  var errMessage = document.getElementById("nf-error-20");
  //jQuery("#nf-field-20-wrap").removeClass("nf-error");
  jQuery("#nf-field-15").removeClass("btn-disable");
  jQuery("#nf-field-20").removeClass("input-error");
  errMessage.textContent = "";
}
function notWorkingem() {
  var errMessage = document.getElementById("nf-error-20");
  //jQuery("#nf-field-20-wrap").addClass("nf-error");
  jQuery("#nf-field-15").addClass("btn-disable");
  jQuery("#nf-field-20").addClass("input-error");
  errMessage.textContent = "You need to provide a business address.";
}
function checkBoGood(){
    var errMsgPp = document.getElementById("nf-error-13");
    jQuery("#nf-field-15").removeClass("btn-disable");
//  errMsgPp.textContent = "";
}
function checkBoBad(){
    var errMsgPp = document.getElementById("nf-error-13");
    jQuery("#nf-field-15").addClass("btn-disable");
}
```

Some things need to be considered here:

1. I am not able to check checkbox status with standard functions because that checkbox also uses a class to check if it is checked or not by adding "nf-checked" class that is why I have to check if that element has the class name "nf-checked" or not. FYI this ninja form.
2. I can't use Document.ready and $ because that is not working in WordPress.
3. All this code I have done myself so please correct me if I am doing some silly mistake. I am very much a beginner in Javascript.
4. If Html helps then I am adding that too below. I am not adding the whole code because I can target element using IDs.

```
<!--Email container Start-->
<div id="nf-field-20-container" class="nf-field-container textbox-container  label-hidden ">
    <div class="nf-before-field">
    </div>
    <div class="nf-field">
        <div id="nf-field-20-wrap" class="field-wrap textbox-wrap" data-field-id="20">
            <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-20" id="nf-label-field-20" class="">Work email address  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="nf-field-element">
                <input type="text" value="" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element input-error" placeholder="Work email address" id="nf-field-20" name="nf-field-20" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="nf-error-20" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-20">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nf-after-field">
        <nf-section>
            <div class="nf-input-limit">
            </div>
            <div id="nf-error-20" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert">You need to provide a business address.</div>    
        </nf-section>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Email container Ends-->

<!--Checkbox Start-->
<div id="nf-field-13-container" class="nf-field-container checkbox-container  label-right one-half first ">
    <div class="nf-before-field">
    </div>
    <div class="nf-field"><div id="nf-field-13-wrap" class="field-wrap checkbox-wrap" data-field-id="13">
        <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-13" id="nf-label-field-13" class=" nf-checked-label">I accept hubsell’s <a href="#">privacy policy</a>.  </label>
        </div>
    <div class="nf-field-element">
        <input id="nf-field-13" name="nf-field-13" aria-describedby="nf-error-13" class="ninja-forms-field nf-checked nf-element" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-13">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nf-after-field"><nf-section>
    <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>
    <div id="nf-error-13" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>
    </nf-section>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Checkbox Ends-->

<!--Submit Start-->
<input id="nf-field-15" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" type="button" value="Submit">
<!--Submit Ends-->
```

```js
window.onload = function ninjaInit() {
  validatEmail();
  validatCheckbox();
  jQuery('#nf-field-20').keyup(validatEmail);
  jQuery('#nf-field-13').change(validatCheckbox);
}

function validatEmail() {
  var email = document.getElementById('nf-field-20');
  //console.log(email.value);
  if (
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!yahoo.co.in)(?!aol.com)(?!live.com)(?!outlook.com)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{2,61}$/.test(email.value)) {
    itWorksem();
  } else {
    notWorkingem();
  }
}

function validatCheckbox() {
  if (!jQuery('#nf-field-13').hasClass("nf-checked")) {
    console.log('checkbox not checked');
    checkBoGood();
  } else {
    console.log('checkbox checked');
    checkBoBad();
  }
}

function itWorksem() {
  var errMessage = document.getElementById("nf-error-20");
  //jQuery("#nf-field-20-wrap").removeClass("nf-error");
  jQuery("#nf-field-15").removeClass("btn-disable");
  jQuery("#nf-field-20").removeClass("input-error");
  errMessage.textContent = "";
}

function notWorkingem() {
  var errMessage = document.getElementById("nf-error-20");
  //jQuery("#nf-field-20-wrap").addClass("nf-error");
  jQuery("#nf-field-15").addClass("btn-disable");
  jQuery("#nf-field-20").addClass("input-error");
  errMessage.textContent = "You need to provide a business address.";
}

function checkBoGood() {
  var errMsgPp = document.getElementById("nf-error-13");
  jQuery("#nf-field-15").removeClass("btn-disable");
  //  errMsgPp.textContent = "";
}

function checkBoBad() {
  var errMsgPp = document.getElementById("nf-error-13");
  jQuery("#nf-field-15").addClass("btn-disable");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Email container Start-->
<div id="nf-field-20-container" class="nf-field-container textbox-container  label-hidden ">
  <div class="nf-before-field">
  </div>
  <div class="nf-field">
    <div id="nf-field-20-wrap" class="field-wrap textbox-wrap" data-field-id="20">
      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-20" id="nf-label-field-20" class="">Work email address  </label>
      </div>
      <div class="nf-field-element">
        <input type="text" value="" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element input-error" placeholder="Work email address" id="nf-field-20" name="nf-field-20" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="nf-error-20" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-20">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nf-after-field">
    <nf-section>
      <div class="nf-input-limit">
      </div>
      <div id="nf-error-20" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert">You need to provide a business address.</div>
    </nf-section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Email container Ends-->

<!--Checkbox Start-->
<div id="nf-field-13-container" class="nf-field-container checkbox-container  label-right one-half first ">
  <div class="nf-before-field">
  </div>
  <div class="nf-field">
    <div id="nf-field-13-wrap" class="field-wrap checkbox-wrap" data-field-id="13">
      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-13" id="nf-label-field-13" class=" nf-checked-label">I accept hubsell’s <a href="#">privacy policy</a>.  </label>
      </div>
      <div class="nf-field-element">
        <input id="nf-field-13" name="nf-field-13" aria-describedby="nf-error-13" class="ninja-forms-field nf-checked nf-element" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-13">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nf-after-field">
    <nf-section>
      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>
      <div id="nf-error-13" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>
    </nf-section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Checkbox Ends-->

<!--Submit Start-->
<input id="nf-field-15" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" type="button" value="Submit">
<!--Submit Ends-->
```

You can see the input[type="checkbox"] has that nf-checked class already I mark the default value as checked in ninja forms.

**Update:** I have added the proper HTML code after ruleboy21 comment.

Comment: Run an event listener on the input field, and check each character if it matches should minimize this greatly.

Comment: Kindly update your HTML. Eg. add the markup for the error elements like `nf-error-20` etc.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK thanks. As I mentioned I am a beginner in this. I'll find a way to try that and let you know.

Comment: @ruleboy21 I have updated my question with proper HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller now

```js
function validateEmail() {
  let email = document.getElementById('nf-field-20');
  let isWorking =
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!yahoo.co.in)(?!aol.com)(?!live.com)(?!outlook.com)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{2,61}$/.test(email.value);
    console.log(isWorking);
  indicateStatus(isWorking);
}

function validateCheckbox() {
  jQuery("#nf-field-15").toggleClass("btn-disable", !jQuery('#nf-field-13').hasClass("nf-checked"));
}

function indicateStatus(isWorking) {
  var errMessage = document.getElementById("nf-error-20");
  jQuery("#nf-field-15").toggleClass("btn-disable", !isWorking);
  jQuery("#nf-field-20").toggleClass("input-error", !isWorking);
  errMessage.textContent = "";
}
window.onload = function ninjaInit() {
  validateEmail();
  validateCheckbox();
  jQuery('#nf-field-20').on('keyup', validateEmail);
  jQuery('#nf-field-13').on('change', validateCheckbox);
}
```

```css
.input-error {
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.btn-disable {
  background-color: #ddffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Email container Start-->
<div id="nf-field-20-container" class="nf-field-container textbox-container  label-hidden ">
  <div class="nf-before-field">
  </div>
  <div class="nf-field">
    <div id="nf-field-20-wrap" class="field-wrap textbox-wrap" data-field-id="20">
      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-20" id="nf-label-field-20" class="">Work email address  </label>
      </div>
      <div class="nf-field-element">
        <input type="text" value="" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element input-error" placeholder="Work email address" id="nf-field-20" name="nf-field-20" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="nf-error-20" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-20">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nf-after-field">
    <nf-section>
      <div class="nf-input-limit">
      </div>
      <div id="nf-error-20" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert">You need to provide a business address.</div>
    </nf-section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Email container Ends-->

<!--Checkbox Start-->
<div id="nf-field-13-container" class="nf-field-container checkbox-container  label-right one-half first ">
  <div class="nf-before-field">
  </div>
  <div class="nf-field">
    <div id="nf-field-13-wrap" class="field-wrap checkbox-wrap" data-field-id="13">
      <div class="nf-field-label"><label for="nf-field-13" id="nf-label-field-13" class=" nf-checked-label">I accept hubsell’s <a href="#">privacy policy</a>.  </label>
      </div>
      <div class="nf-field-element">
        <input id="nf-field-13" name="nf-field-13" aria-describedby="nf-error-13" class="ninja-forms-field nf-checked nf-element" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="" aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-13">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nf-after-field">
    <nf-section>
      <div class="nf-input-limit"></div>
      <div id="nf-error-13" class="nf-error-wrap nf-error" role="alert"></div>
    </nf-section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Checkbox Ends-->

<!--Submit Start-->
<input id="nf-field-15" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element" type="button" value="Submit">
<!--Submit Ends-->
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working for input and checkbox. the only weird thing is that checkbox is checked by default so it has no `nf-checked` class present and the email field is red marked because no value is in there but the button is available to click. and when I untick and tick the checkbox again the button becomes unavailable. It's like code listening to the checkbox after one untick and tick action. The same thing was happening with my code but surely you cut the code drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JavaScript with this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // add all the names of the fields you want to validate in this object
    // if the field has a valid default value, give it a value of true else pass false
    let successBag = {
        'nf-field-20': false,
        'nf-field-13': true
    };

    // function to disable the submit button
    function disableForm(key, value){
        if(key) successBag[key] = value;
        if(Object.values(successBag).includes(false)){
            $("#nf-field-15").attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass("btn-disable");
        }else{
            $("#nf-field-15").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass("btn-disable");
        }
    }
    // disable/enable the form by default
    disableForm(null, null);

    $('#nf-field-20').on('input', function(){
        let errMessage = $("#nf-error-20");

        if(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]{2,4})+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,8})+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(this.value)){
            $(this).removeClass("input-error");
            errMessage.text("");
            disableForm(this.name, true);
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("input-error");
            errMessage.text("You need to provide a business address.");
            disableForm(this.name, false);
        }
    });
    $('#nf-field-13').on('change', function(){
        let errMessage = $("#nf-error-13");

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            errMessage.text("");
            disableForm(this.name, true);
        }else{
            errMessage.text("Privacy policy is required.");
            disableForm(this.name, false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed my JS to this. It didn't give any console errors but it didn't work also. Like if the input field is empty it should disable the button and show an error below the field. It didn't show. I placed a few console messages to see if the code is completing its journey to the end and it is completing its journey. FYI I changed both field defaults to false but got the same results. I see you are using :checked selector but I mentioned in my question that will not work. I am still seeing your solution and will do my edits and try to make it work. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Robin when you put a `console.log` in the change event does it work?

Comment: No. The code circles around the change event but doesn't go in it. tried clicking on the checkbox several times. I didn't get any error which is was getting before using jQuery(document).ready(function($) in my code. I tried to change to mine window.onload = function ninjaInit() but it threw an error of unexpected ')' so I reverted back to yours.

Comment: Update: The code does go into disableForm function but doesn't go in input and change event.

Comment: I think you're targeting the wrong fields. Check the `id` of the input if it's indeed `nf-field-20`.

Comment: I checked it. See Ninja forms assign a number to each field and after this when it gets rendered, that number will be in IDs, Classes and errors of that field. So I am targeting the rights fields and can confirm with the HTML pasted.

Comment: If the website is online you can send me a link so I can take a proper look. It's something easy, but I don't think I have enough info to handle it.

Comment: I won't be able to do that because of NDA with my client. But no problem, Thank you for your efforts. I am going to paste the entire form HTML in the code pen here: https://codepen.io/rjeet0/pen/MWOmWEb and save the question for future reviewers to look at. I will try the event listener solution suggested by other user.